# DELIMITER MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a delimiter, I use Mysql version 8.0 on Ubuntu and when I run the command it returns a syntax error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 BEFORE INSERT ON whatsapps FOR EACH ROW BEG' at line 1
Error position:

    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger1; 
    DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 
BEFORE INSERT ON whatsapps FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM whatsapps; 
    IF @cnt >= 2 THEN CALL sth(); 
    END IF; 
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Can anyone understand which syntax is wrong?

Comment: should `DELIMITER $$` be on its own line?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question

Comment: move `CREATE TRIGGER` to the next line, see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

DELIMITER must be on its own line.

DELIMITER uses *all* of the content until the end of the line to define the delimiter. So in your example, you have set the delimiter to this string of 27 characters: "$$ CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 "